# SonarQube authorisation Error. You're not authorized to analyze this project or the project doesn't exist on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

About three months ago the scanning worked without problems. Now it gives an error: "You're not authorized to analyze this project or the project doesn't exist on SonarQube and you're not authorized to create it. Please contact an administrator."

```
Sonarqube 10.2.1.78527
Sonar-scanner-5.0.1.3006-windows
```

Properties:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar \
-Dsonar.projectKey=Module-AccessControl-Backend \
-Dsonar.projectName='Module-AccessControl-Backend' \
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
-Dsonar.token=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

sonar.properties:
I only changed `sonar.web.port=9000`
And settings for connect to database

This data properties worked 3 months ago without problems.

What I tried to do:

1. Created a new token in the account settings.
2. Created a new token for the project when creating the project.
3. Disabled the "Force user authentication" setting.
4. I even tried changing the port on the sonar.
5. I tried adding sonar.login and sonar.password to sonar.properties file.
6. Updated sonar from version 9.8 to 10.2.1.78527

Nothing helped. Only the third point, when changed, slightly changes the meaning and text of the error, but the problem is the same.